# How to get libc on Openwrt?

Tags: linux, openwrt

I'm trying to get libc on OpenWrt as a package, but I can't seem to find it in any of the repositories. I am only able to find the `.ipk` [here.](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/x86/64/packages/base/)

How do I get it on my configuration as I'm compiling it instead of using `opkg`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I correctly understand your question.
If you are compiling the Openwrt, the `.ipk` should be under `<buildroot/bin>`. If you would like to just download it, please select the right architecture, for example using `ar71xx` use the link below: [ar71xx - 15.05.1](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/)

On the other hand I cant imagine a system without libc installed, please type the following:

```
opkg list-installed | grep libc
```

Comment: I don't want to just install it. I want to build and compile it as a package.

Comment: As I understand you have two ways to go:
1. Build the complete OpenWRT image, and as a part of this, you are going to build libc as well. Please follow this guide: [OpenWRT build](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/build) 
Make sure to select the right target before building it.
2. Download the SDK for your target. Here you also have to select the right target, for example OpenWRT 15.05.1 SDK for `ar71xx` architecture can be found [here](https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/OpenWrt-SDK-15.05.1-ar71xx-generic_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2.Linux-x86_64.tar.bz2)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the OpenWrt SDK.
2. Update and install the packages.

   ```
   cd ~/OpenWrt-SDK-15...
   ./scripts/feeds update -a 
   ./scripts/feeds install -a
   ```
3. Compile the libc package

   ```
   make package/libc/compile -j1 V=s
   ```
4. Find it in bin/packages/...

If it fails find the `libc package` for OpenWrt and copy to `/feeds/packages/libs`. Update the package by typing `./scripts/feeds/update -i && ./scripts/feeds/install libc` and go to the step 4 again.